# Store image location in database or generate them on the fly based on id

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've been refactoring some code and throwing away some old spaghetti. I am now faced with the following issue:

I have tv episodes which have a screenshot source file and 4 thumbnails. The current code generates the paths during the creation of the thumbnails and also when they are loaded. So the actual path to the image is never stored anywhere. It is generated based on the database id of the episode (using md5 hashes).

This quickly became a mess. Now I decided I store the path to the src and all 4 sizes in a simple json array and plug it into the database.

The question is whether this has any significant downsides? The entire json string is always between 500 and 550 chars.

Or should I stick to the on the fly generation of the paths and figure out a more maintainable way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think either way is valid, but find easier to handle md5, as you dont have to handle json deserialization an variable extraction, simply create the hash and file path.

May be the issue has to be with processing of several md5 hashes, vs storing several json data.

Just choose the one you like more.